# 2d-bin-packing Algorithm to place a rectangle in x,y location?

Tags: c#, java, javascript, c++, algorithm

I am implementing 2d-bin-packing algorithm in canvas. My task is to place rectangles as optimal as it can be on a canvas.

the following shows how to do it: 
http://incise.org/2d-bin-packing-with-javascript-and-canvas.html

BUT, it starts with the origin. I would like to tell the algorithm where to put a rectangle and that the next one not to be on top of him.

What should be changed in the code?

Is there another algorithm to use for it?

Comment: On what language? You've put 4 language tags.