# How to optimally displace two polygons?

Tags: math, graphics, geometry, polygon, computational-geometry

Given two convex polygons (which may or may not overlap) they should be layed out (such that they don't overlap - see comments) in the "tightest possible way". (I.e. they should take up as little screen real estate as possible.)  Formally let's define the "tightest possible way" to be the one whose bounding box is of the minimum area (but I'm open to other sensible definitions as well :)).  (NB: Everything here is in 2D.) A bonus would be to even consider the ratio of the sides of the bounding box (e.g. that it should be 16:9) but I suspect it'd be too much to ask :).

Is there a better-than-brute-force algorithm to do this? (Brute force would be like laying them out in "every possible" direction and calculate the area of the bounding box.)  I've been looking for a solution but I haven't found one; though it doesn't look to be a very unique problem to me...

---

This is what I do now (which is *approximate only* to the requirements above):  I take one polygon fixed (`p1`) and calculate its center point (`c1`). I then find the point on the circumflex of `p1` which is the closest to `c1` (let's call it `x`). (Note: The `(c1, x)` vector will define the direction of movement of `p2`.)  Let's then define the separatng axis as a line perpendicluar to `(c1,x)` at `x`. (The two polygons will touch at `x` at the end.)  Then I calculate y which is the farthest point of `p2`(!) from the separating axis in the direction of `(x,c1)` (vector reversed!); let's call its distance `d`.  I then move `p2` in the direction of `(c1,x)` by `d`.

It ensures that `p2` is as close to the center of `p1` as possible - unfortunately with regard to `p1` only.  But it does not take `p2`'s shape into account so it may be that they can be placed "tighter" by choosing a different displacement direction.

Comment: "layed out" meaning they don't overlap in their new positions, right?

Comment: Are you working with any frameworks? There are some algorithms and indexes that might be able to handle some of this for you, or at least greatly increase the speed.

Comment: @japreiss: yes, that's what I meant

Comment: Bounding boxes may not give the right picture. A tightly aligned polygon set could have a bigger AxisAligned BB.... A Convex hull would probably suit the bill better

Comment: @radpin: no but I may if it helps (currently it's barebone Javascript) -- what kind of framework do you think of?

Comment: @Kshitij Banerjee: cool, a minimal convex hull would suit me just as well

Comment: @fastcatch : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637785/difficult-2d-bin-packing-algorithm-to-place-a-rectangle-in-x-y-location something like that. There's a 50 page PDF linked in there that goes over a lot of options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not specify containment conditions,

If one is smaller than the other, fit it inside the larger polygon. Thats the tightest fit :)

Otherwise align the centers, and rotate one of them till the convex-hulls/ BB are the smallest.

**Edit**

Okay, i read the comments about non overlap later.. :)

So take one of the polygon, and overlap all its side with all the other polygons sides, The orientation that gives you the least area wins. This is definitely O( 2 * N1 * N2 )  // 2 slides to match the vertices for each overlap.

The overlap of sides is such that the centers of the polygons are towards opposite sides of the shared edge only.. Since they are both convex polygons, they wont intersect and hence no overlap if one of the sides are overlapping.

[image: Slides at vertices]

Comment: that would overlap of areas or not? and also I do not know if rotation is possible for his purposes

Comment: Originally I would've gone without rotation; I may consider rotating one of them if that helps a lot.  (See it's kind of a "soft" problem: end user expectation goes along the lines that the whole thing should "look nice" :).)

Comment: Im guessing rotating them and making one of the edges itself the separating axis would give you much tighter results. But then see what helps you best.. :)

Answer (score 0):

interesting problem I would approach like this:

1. **translate polygons to safe distance**

   - compute bounding boxes
   - translate one polygon so the bounding boxes are `almost` touching and do not overlap
   - let `ax0,ax1,ay0,ay1` be the bounding box for one polygon (the top one)
   - and `bx0,bx1,by0,by1` be the bounding box for the other one (the bottom one)
   - let `ay0<=ay1` , `by0<=by1` , and up means y axis + direction
   - so `dy = by1 - ay0 + d`
   - where `dy` is the translation of first (red) polygon (just add it to all y coordinates)
   - and `d` is the safety gap you want between them
     [image: bbox translation]
2. **find low and top halves of polygons**

   - like on this image:
     [image: polygon y-halves]
   - sort Vertexes by CW
   - then compute `dx=x(i)-x(i-1)` per vertice
   - if `dx > 0` it is top half else bottom half
3. **now try moving red polygon back down**

   - you have to check just bottom part of the top polygon
   - with top part of the bottom polygon
   - which should speed things up quite a bit
   - step of movement should be a fraction of `min(d,ay1-ay0,by1-by0)`
   - now just move top polygon down by step
   - if no intersection between neighbouring halves occur repeat last step
   - else move top polygon up by safety gap > step and this is solution

[Notes]

- you should handle edge cases like bounding boxes does not overlap (side by side)
- handle touching of lines as intersection
- you can try both variants (which polygon is first and which second) and choose better solution
- may be is safer to have vertices `dx==0` in booth top and down halves

Comment: Thanks. If I understand correctly yours would not try to "move" the "a" polygon around "b" - so that if "a" is initially "top left" of "b" it gets stuck there.  (I know it's technically not correctly described but I hope you see the point.)  I'll edit the original post with my current - definitely suboptimal - solution.

Comment: @fastcatch yes it is just movement up/down in y axis as your original question text incline ... for general 2D shift it would be generic bin-packing problem ... there should be plenty of questions about that here ... if the polygons are side by side you can always stop if new `ay1 <= by1` ...

Comment: do you know for sure if it's bin-packing-hard?  Because that's NP-hard and thus trying all possible directions is the best way to go.

Comment: if you can move and/or rotate in any direction (not with some specific consraints) then YES the only thing you can do use some heuristic or quality/complexity compromise like convex hull ... sometimes field approach get nice easy and fast results but it is unstable ...